# how to make search bar able only when there is more than 3 characters in search field

Tags: ionic-framework

This is my search bar that start searching its value when we enter any input but either single character. I want to customize this (ionInput)=getItems($event) so that it works only when input is more than 3 characters

```
 <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
 <ion-list *ngFor="let product of products" >
<ion-item text-wrap  (click)="openProductPage(product.id,product.name)">
     <h2> {{ product.name }} </h2>     
</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want not to activate searching process, then the below code is enough.

```
getItems(event){
  if(!event.target.value || event.target.value.length < 3){
     return;
  }
  // search 
}
```